# Open ppt from URL in android

Tags: android, powerpoint

In my android app, I required open .ppt file from server url. But I don't 
find any how I can open in my app or any third party app.

For example: Url > http://example.com/ppt/11_4_201611_04_22AM.ppt

If you know please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Step 1: Download the file (e.g., to internal storage). Step 2: Set up `FileProvider` to publish the file. Step 3: Create an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, for the `Uri` that you get from `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`, and the appropriate MIME type. Step 4: Call `startActivity()` with that `Intent`. Step 5. If `startActivity()` throws `ActivityNotFoundException`, tell the user that there is no PPT viewer on their device.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any way to open from URL without download ?

Comment: There is no requirement for an Android device to have *any* app that displays PPT files, let alone one that will support the `http` scheme. Your odds of getting a supported app increase if you download the PPT yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you have about three options
1) open it via google docs like below

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.containWebView);
webview.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClients());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
            + "YOUR_DOC_URL_HERE"); 
 public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
 }
}
```

2) download the file and pass it through an intent to Microsoft powerpoint app

```
import android.support.v4.app.ShareCompat;
Uri pptUri = Uri.parse("file://sdcard/sdcard0/test.ppt");                
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                                     .setText("open ppt")
                                         .setType("application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
                                         .setStream(pptUri )
                                         .getIntent()
                                 .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

3) download the file and use third party library to help you parsing the file and displaying it like [itsrts/pptVieweer](https://github.com/itsrts/pptviewer-android/issues) but look at issues first , as you cant release a signed apk while using this library.